# Font Awesome automatically changes icons on click

Tags: font-awesome

I am using fontawesome (4.4) in rails (4.2.3) (via the font-awesome-rails gem).

Upon clicking on any of the fontawesome icons in my rails app, the icon changes to an angle-right (and on repeated clicking, it toggles between angle-right and angle-down). I am not doing anything in my code or css to cause that change.

I have opened [an issue](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/issues/150) on font-awesome-rails for this.

*Update 1: I am using ckeditor-rails gem which bundles some version of fontawesome. Removing ckeditor-rails fixes the problem. How do I debug/resolve it?*

For example, if I have:

```
<%= link_to fa_icon 'fa-envelope lg', email_path %>
```

The initial html is:

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>
```

After clicking once, it becomes:

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg fa-angle-right"></i>
```

Clicking again makes it

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg fa-angle-down"></i>
```

Clicking repeatedly beyond that toggles between `angle-right` and `angle-down`.

I have the following relevant gems:

```
bootstrap-sass (3.3.5.1)
font-awesome-rails (4.4.0.0)
rails (4.2.3)
sass (3.4.17)
sass-rails (5.0.3)
sprockets (3.3.3)
sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
```

Here is my full [Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/rcanand/44a124b334172651fb17)

Comment: have you examined the page element to see what the markup is doing when you click it? I'd be inclined to think something in the gem is causing this behavior, or elsewhere on your page. Have you tried isolating the icons to a separate project and seeing if the behavior persists?

Comment: @LeeHarrison I have updated the question with the markup and its changes. I have tried a few different combinations of the gem versions (sass-rails, bootstrap-sass, font-awesome-rails, but this behavior did not change.